# Overwrite admin controller in version 1.6

Tags: overrides, magento-1.6, admin-controller

I am trying to overwrite the controller located at: `app/core/code/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php`

First of all I tried just making a copy in my local code directory `app/local/code/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php` keeping the file exactly the same and just making it `die()` so I knew if it was getting executed. But this didn't work and I read somewhere that you can't simply just drop an admin controller into the `local` directory.

Considering this, my next option is to write a module and use the `config.xml` to "rewrite" the controller. Thankfully I am able to add the functionality I require to a module that I have already been working on so I don't need to create a module simply for this task. So in my `config.xml` I added:

```
<config>

    ....

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mycompany_Prime before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mycompany_Prime_Adminhtml</Mycompany_Prime>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    .....
```

`<admin/>` is a direct child of `<config/>`.

Then I created my new controller under `app/code/local/Mycompany/Prime/controllers/Adminhtml/ProductController.php` with:

```
require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php";

class Mycompany_Prime_Adminhtml_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController {

....
```

However the class never gets executed. For that matter, neither does the script:

```
die('Here');
require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php";

class Mycompany_Prime_Adminhtml_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController {
```

Any help on overwriting this admin controller would be appreciated. I am using Magento version 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should be placed in the file
`app/code/local/Mycompany/Prime/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/ProductController.php` instead of `app/code/local/Mycompany/Prime/controllers/Adminhtml/ProductController.php`.

Change the class name accordingly also.