# how to override the product controller in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin

how to override the catalog/product/new action, but I am not understanding where I start. I have searched on different forums but I couldn't get any idea.
I have tried it by overriding the copy in local but could not succeed.

Comment: check [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71285/overwrite-admin-controller-in-version-1-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override the product controller follow this 
create file in `app/etc/modules/Solsint_Proextended.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Solsint_Proextended>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Solsint_Proextended>
  </modules>
</config>
```

create file in `app/code/local/Solsint/Proextended/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Solsint_Proextended>
<version>0.1.0</version>
</Solsint_Proextended>
</modules>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Solsint_Proextended before="Mage_Adminhtml">Solsint_Proextended</Solsint_Proextended>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin> 

</config>
```

and at the end create file in `app/code/local/Solsint/Proextended/controllers/catalog/ProductController.php`

```
<?php
include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php");
class Solsint_Proextended_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{

public function newAction()
{
  echo "Working"; exit; //do here what you want to do
}
}
```

this is tested code. hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: let my try this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a small module for overriding the Controller.let see step by step for overriding

Step 1:- Create YourPackageName_Adminhtml.xml file at app/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <YourPackageName_Adminhtml>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    <YourPackageName_Adminhtml>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2:- Create config.xml file at app/code/local/YourPackageName/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourPackageName_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </YourPackageName_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <yourpackagename_adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">YourPackageName_Adminhtml</yourpackagename_adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Step 3:- Create ProductController.php controller file at app/code/local/YourPackageName/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php

```
<?php
    include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php");
    class YourPackageName_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
    {
        public function newAction()
        {
            // echo "done"; exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Note:- for more information on overriding the create new product in admin refer http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-override-create-new-product.html

Comment: your answer is also helpful but i already choose correct ans, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use phpstorm and magicento plugin for easy override anything you want.
2. Class name for rewrite Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
3. Rewrite class may be not best way to do what you want. You should try use observers first.

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php';
class YOURMODULENAMESPACE_YOURMODULENAME_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{
    public function newAction()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

And add rewrite to controller address:

```
        <rewrite>
            <module_catalog_product>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/.*/catalog_product/new/#]]></from>
               <to>/YOURCONTROLLERADDRESS/adminhtml_catalog_product/new/</to>
            </module_catalog_product>
        </rewrite>
```

Comment: That's the old way of doing things. Please don't do this, unless you need to keep compatibility with older versions. Older versions that no longer get security patches I might add.