# New customer registration assigned a registration date in the future (we have 8 customers that registered as far as December 2nd, 2018)

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, registration

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

We haven't changed any settings but strange things are starting to happen such as when the customer registers on the website - it is assigning the incorrect date value. Also we are having problems with cookies (getting the "Shopping Cart is Empty" Error which usually happens for us when the date/time is out of sync somehow).

One customer registered today and it says:

Account Created on: Jun 5, 2018 9:16:27 AM which is obviously not possible.

**Is there a setting on the server that needs to be changed so that it is reporting the correct date/time? Or what other setting within Magento needs to be checked?**

I just did a sort by the date and it appears that we have 8 customers in total with future registration dates all the way up to December 2nd, 2018.

I contacted the hosting company and this is what they replied:

"*Thank you for your reply!
Sun May 6 16:39:06 -06 2018 - the server date and time are correct.
Where's the registration form taking it's date/time feed from?
Perhaps you need to look this up on your Magento installation.
If it's set to lookup the server time upon registration, it will be the correct one.*"

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , I resolved it by overriding save action , as mentioned here -[how to override the product controller in admin panel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87649/how-to-override-the-product-controller-in-admin-panel)

and setting created at attribute manually to store's time and date as follows;

```
$product->setData('created_at',Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue with product created_at column
you have to use

```
Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()
```

instead of

```
$zendDate->getIso()
```

[Override model as mention here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

below is the solution.

open following file : **app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Time\Created.php**

and comment out beforeSave() function and replace with following function code.

```
public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();

    $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);

    if (is_null($date)) {
        if ($object->isObjectNew()) {

            $object->setData($attributeCode, Varien_Date::now());
        }
    } else {
        // convert to UTC
        $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));

        // Replace -> $zendDate->getIso() with Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()
        $object->setData($attributeCode, Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate());
    }

        return $this;
    }
```

[Detail reference link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/customer-created-at-date-off-by-months/31225?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

i am sure it will help to you.